# Where does the anonymous feedback go to?

Tags: discussion, feedback

When viewing ELU as an anonymous user, you can provide feedback on the usefulness of an answer by clicking on *Yes* or *No* buttons. I'm curious as to where this feedback goes and if it is used in any manner.

Comment: It goes to the SE team. What they do with it, no idea. Actually, when they first introduced it, they specifically said, "no idea what this is good for, we'll collect first, evaluate what to do with it later". Mods can only see very little, namely an aggregated number (how many times in total this feature was used on a particular day, but not even on what questions).

Comment: @RegDwighт Cheers. I guess I'll stop clicking the bloody things then :)

Comment: I don't know if it's the same here, but on beta sites, you can see the feedback with the "10K" privilege (which comes at 2K). You can see which posts were rated well and which were rated poorly. It also shows you underrated and overrated posts.

Comment: @Luke: the corresponding link for ELU is [`tools/post-feedback`](http://english.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) (10k only).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99370/192187